# I receive exception No Persistence provider for EntityManager in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, intellij-idea, persistence

Someone to knows where can be the problem - [image]

> Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

I use IntelliJ and h2 database connection with Hibernate

There are my classes:

persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress DeprecatedClassUsageInspection -->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="StudentPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>model.StudentInfo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/JPA_App" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                      value="false" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Entity class:

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class StudentInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "lastname", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

and Main class

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class AddStudent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudentPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        StudentInfo student = new StudentInfo();
        student.setId(0);
        student.setName("John");
        student.setLastname("Doe");

        em.persist(student);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }
}
```

In eclipse this simple source works but in IntelliJ I received this exception.
I would be grateful for any ideas to resolve this error.

Best regards,

D. Balamjiev

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `META-INF` folder at the root of one of build paths of your IDE.
For example, move `META-INF` folder to the `web` folder and it should be available at the runtime.

By using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle, you would not have these kinds of problem any longer since the layout is standard and therefore the same whatever the IDE you are using.
For example, in your case, it would be both for Eclipse and IntelliJ : `src/main/resources/META-INF`